# Adding a Hash in an Array

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create an array of hashes in perl and I'm having some trouble in printing it as the only thing that prints out is the last hash entered.

Is there something wrong in how I push the hashtables into the array? Also, how can I print the contents of the array (the hashtables) properly?

```
print "\n===========SUBJECTS===========\n";
my $exit = "n";
until ( $exit eq "y" ) {    #loops until user enters 'y'
    print "Course Number: ";
    my $cNum = <STDIN>;
    chomp($cNum);

    print "Course Credit: ";
    my $cCred = <STDIN>;

    print "Grade: ";
    my $cGrade = <STDIN>;

    %subHash = (
        "courseNumber" => $cNum,
        "courseCredit" => $cCred,
        "courseGrade"  => $cGrade,
    );
    push @subList, \%subHash;
    $subCount += 1;

    print "\nFinished adding subjects?\n[y/n]\nCHOICE: ";    #asks for subject input termination
    $exit = <STDIN>;
    chomp($exit);
    print "\n==============================\n";
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to print `@subList`?

Comment: Declare an new subHash each time `my %subHash = ...`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer has already been given to you. Are you having trouble copy and pasting it into your homework?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @subList;
print "\n===========SUBJECTS===========\n";
my $exit = "n";
until ( $exit eq "y" ) {    #loops until user enters 'y'
    print "Course Number: ";
    my $cNum = <STDIN>;
    chomp($cNum);

    print "Course Credit: ";
    my $cCred = <STDIN>;
    chomp($cCred);

    print "Grade: ";
    my $cGrade = <STDIN>;
    chomp($cGrade);

    push @subList, {
        "courseNumber" => $cNum,
        "courseCredit" => $cCred,
        "courseGrade"  => $cGrade,
    };

    print "\nFinished adding subjects?\n[y/n]\nCHOICE: ";    #asks for subject input termination
    $exit = <STDIN>;
    chomp($exit);
    print "\n==============================\n";
}

foreach my $hashref ( @subList ) {
    while ( my ($key, $val) = each %{$hashref} ) {
        print "$key => $val\n";
    }
    print "-----\n";
}
```

Comment: Rude, but I don't have a choice since I'm the one asking, huh? Anyway, As I've said earlier, I've done that before(even before posting here, actually) and it only prints either the last input entered or a jumbled mess of the last and second to the last inputs.

Comment: Did you even try running what I posted? It literally does exactly what you requested so it seems rude that you would suggest it doesn't. The code you posted even has errors as you don't chomp all your user inputs.

Comment: I did try your work. It did work. Comparing what you did to mine, I found out that Ithe problem is in how I push my hashes into the array. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with your hash is you are overriding your hash every loop because you aren't declaring it as a local to the block. If you had put 'my %subHash =' instead of just '%subHash =' it would have worked (as mentioned by Chris Charley 'Declare an new subHash each time my %subHash = ...'). In my example I use an anonymous hash reference which is local as well. You also forgot to chomp $cCred and $cGrade.

Comment: I see. So declaring a 'my %subHash' at the start of the program wouldn't work? (The above snippet was inside an if-statement which is then inside a while loop.)

Comment: No, because you are writing to the same key names every time. i.e. $subHash{courseGrade} = A on first loop, then on the second loop you are setting it like $subHash{courseGrade} = B. Since subHash exists outside the loop (kinda the same as declaring it inside the loop without 'my') you are just changing that variable. By using an anonymous hash or my %hash inside the loop you are essentially assigning to a new memory address (variable) each iteration of the loop so it is not getting overridden and you get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the array of hash refs, dereferencing each one appropriately.

```
for my $hash_ref (@AoH)
{
    for my $key (keys %{$hash_ref})
    {
        print "$key => $hash_ref->{$key}\n"
    }
}
```

or

```
for my $hash_ref (@AoH)
{
    while (my ($key, $val) = each %{$hash_ref})
    {
        print "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

See [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more about nested data structures, including printing them out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I've already tried this. It didn't print the key-value pair properly, only printing the part of the second to the last input and the last one.

Comment: @user4048412 Use `Data::Dumper` module and print your data structure. You can then inspect if it is getting constructed as you intended it to be.

Comment: @user4048412 Can you edit your question to show the code? It's very difficult to find the problem with a piece of code without knowing what that code is.